# How to reference another table using MySQL in Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm editing an app that uses NodeJS and MySQL.

I would like to make a reference from a table (album) to another (photo). (A album will have photos...)

When using Nodejs + Mongo, we use `mongoose.Schema` and `type: Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref: "Schema_name"` in the model file.
But how I can do it when using Mysql?

[How I do it using Mongo on a NodeJS app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttoga.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MySQL foreign key for this,
ie,

the primary key in one table will be foreign key in another table in order to make reference.in your scenario the primary key in album (something like album id) can be foreign key in photo

for more info refer the link given below,

[create-table-foreign-keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering. But how can I refer a foreign key in Nodejs Model file?